# Writing a while loop to find multiples of 7 from 1 to 9999

Tags: java

I am trying to write a while loop like the question indicates that returns the multiples of 7 in decreasing order. At first I was trying to just write a code to return the values before I made then decreasing, but my while loop won't execute. I added a statement printing "Start" just to make sure it was running.

```
System.out.println("Start");
int number = 7;
int count = 9999;       
while (number <= count);
{
System.out.print(number);
number = number + 7;
}
```

I wrote it this way to be simpler and because I was unsure of how to make number into a string of values and check each one. Any help on this is appreciated. Thank you!

**RESOLVED. Sorry first time on site and I am not sure if there is another way to close this, but thanks to multiple users point out the semi colon and Vikas pointing out the println error, the code runs. As to making it decreasing I just swapped a few things around:

```
System.out.println("Start");
int number = 9999;
int count = 7;      
while (number >= count)
    {System.out.println(number);
    number = number - 7;
    }


}
```

Comment: the ; at the end of the "while" line definitely does not belong there.  Try removing it.

Comment: `;` after `while` loop.. just **kills** it :-)

Comment: btw, this returns the numbers in increasing order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to see the output value for number because it is `println` and not `print`

`System.out.print(number);`

Change this to

`System.out.println(number);`

And also as others have answered, remove the semi colon ; at the end of while loop.

Having said this, since you want the result to be printed from Descending to Ascending use below code,

```
System.out.println("Start");
int number = 7;
int count = 9996;       
while (number <= count)
    {
        System.out.println(count);
        count = count - number;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the println clarification. I had removed the braces due to other comments but when I put them back and added println the values all came up. Do you know how I can make them decreasing instead of increasing?

Comment: I fixed it using a slightly different method. I updated it in the info. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

You have an extra semicolon after the while(). Remove it.

With the semicolon at the end of this line, the while loop has an empty body. The following statements in curly braces are executed *after* the loop has finished. But the loop will never finish, because the condition is always true, because `number` never changes.

```
while (number <= count);
```

Change it to:

```
while (number <= count)
{
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a semicolon at the end of your while loop:

```
while (number <= count);
```

which will make it an empty loop. And the following curly braces will only act as a code block and not loop

Comment: I changed it to:                                                                                  while (number <= count)                                       System.out.print(number);
number = number + 7;                but all the output shows is "Start" for a brief second, then keeps running and doesn' terminate.

Comment: If i keep the braces and add println like Vikas V stated, they all print out. Now I just don't know how to get the order decreasing. Like I said in my question I was writing this part of the code first to get it out of the way and I got stuck.

Comment: Try this : while (count > 0);
{
System.out.println(count );
count = count - 7;
}

Comment: @JunedAhsan your answer still has ; at the end of the while(...) which does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 9999;
while (count >= 1) {
    if (count % 7 == 0) {
        System.out.println(count);
    }
    count--;
}
```

Comment: This makes more sense and gives you an insight on the method solving.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and it also worked

```
System.out.println("Start");
int number = 9999;
int count = 7;      
while (number >= count){
  if(number%7==0)
System.out.println(number);
number--;
}}}
```